# Can you make a universal storyboards app with only a single storyboard file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, porting, uistoryboard, universal

Can you make a universal app with storyboards without the ipad storyboard file, just the iphone storyboard file and use the iPhone storyboard file for iPad too?

Comment: you want a universal app, but it only works on iPhone?

Comment: No, I want to be able to make a universal app using storyboards. Xcode supplys 2 one for the different devices. I want to be able to copy the iphone storyboard into the ipad

Comment: Yes, iOS 8 or later, you can create - **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647621/how-whether-to-make-a-universal-storyboard-in-xcode/25445911#25445911**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Universal** application means that you are building the application for both **iPad** and **iPhone (iPod too)** devices.

**iPhone / iPod** means that you are building the application ***only*** for **iPhone and iPod**.

When you start a new project, Xcode asks you if you want to make the  application **Universal** or for **iPhone / iPod** only.

If you already have a project, you can go into **Targets** > **Summary** > **Devices** and from there you can set the type of the application.

Then you select the **Main Storyboard** for **iPhone** (in this case) and you are done.

**EDIT**

By reading your comment, you should make the app Universal and then set a new Storyboard for your iPad version (i.e. mainStoryboard~iPad.xib).

Then just make the content identical to the iPhone's storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

In the project settings (click on your project at the very top of the project navigator) in the summary tab for your target, you can specify two different files to use as main storyboard files for both iphone and ipad.  In this case, just specify the same file for both devices

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as the answer above recommends copying the content to an identical storyboard.