# xCode layouts not scaling correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to create a universal app capable for all devices, but it is not scaling correctly. Below (the correct version) is a screenshot of my iPhone 5s, and the one that is out of scale is a screenshot of my iPad 2.

[image: the correct version]

[image: the incorrect version]

Am I doing it correctly making it scale? Or should I use 2 storyboards and assign one to iPhone, and one to iPad?

Comment: Its good to make two different xib. But for small screen you have to apply proper auto sizing then it will not be a problem.

Comment: I am applying the autoresizing in the bottom right hand corner of the storyboard editor?

Comment: See my answer. I think it will solve most of your problem but you may have change a little bit.

Comment: And disable Autolayout. Please upvote and accept it as answer if helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The better way of doing this is making two separate storyboards.** One for iPhone and other for iPad. This offers you the flexibility to play with both in your own ways and there are many cool things that you can work out with iPads. And to do that, you need separate storyboards in your app. It eliminates the dependency between the look and feel of both the devices.

For making two storyboards the easy way, see this :

[How/whether to make a universal storyboard in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647621/how-whether-to-make-a-universal-storyboard-in-xcode)

For the selection of appropriate storyboards based on devices, check this :

[Selecting different storyboards based on device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672023/selecting-different-storyboards-based-on-device-type)

This might help you immensely.

Comment: Will it automatically pick up what storyboard it should choose? Or will I have to tell it which one? and how can I do this?

Comment: See my updated answer. Those links might help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Its good to make two different xib. But for small screen you have to apply proper auto sizing then it will not be a problem. You can use this for example
[image]

For Section 1:[image]

For Section 2:[image]

For Section 3:[image]

and

For Section 4&5:[image]